# Stack + variable behaviour

Tags: javascript, stack

I just have a  small confusion on understanding the stack execution and variables. Below is the code .

```
  var getDetails=false;

   function firstFunction(){
      getDetails=true;

//      ajax call

   }

   function secondFunction(){
      getDetails=false;
     subFunction();
   }

    fucntion subFunction(){
        if(getDetails){

     }
    }
```

As you noticed there is one global variable , i am setting the value of global variable in both first and second function and make use of it in my subFucntion.

Now lets say i call fistFunction( this function makes an ajax call and gets data little late).
Now while fistFunction is executing i will second function where i am changing the global variable and i also call subFucntion which  uses the global variable .Now lets say while subfunction is executing even my FirstFunction is also executing what will be the value of global variable?

Comment: JavaScript is single-threaded.

Answer (score 1):

In your code above, `getDetails` is definitely `false` when you call `subFunction`, since you set it to `false` immediately before calling `subFunction`.

You have a misconception about how Javascript works:

> while subfunction is executing my FirstFunction is also executing

That situation cannot occur.

Javascript is single-threaded, so there can only ever be one function executing at a time. An AJAX call, like a setTimeout, is asynchronous, but the callback function will only execute once your other execution path has completed, the earliest point that the thread becomes available after the response is ready. If the thread is busy executing another function, then your callback will not run until it is done.

Try this for an example:

```
var start = new Date().getTime();
// Logs first
console.log('Start time: ', start); 

// Asynchronous, but still won't run until after the spin lock finishes
// A result of Javascript being single-threaded
setTimeout(function(){
    // Logs last
    console.log('Asynchronous callback time: ', new Date().getTime());
}, 500);

// Two second spin-lock
while(start + 2000 > new Date().getTime());

// Logs second
console.log('Spin lock finished', new Date().getTime());
```